# Pass variable into Zend Form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a zend form instantiated

```
$form = Form_Example();
```

Now I want to pass an ID from my controller to my form.

So I did this:

```
$form = Form_Example(array('id' => $id));
```

Inside the form I try to call it through:

```
$this->id
```

But it isn't there.

Anybody knows how to get that id into the form?

Thanks

Comment: i think this link help http://www.carlowens.me/2010/04/passing-arguments-from-controller-into-a-zend-form/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you have setter for the the element, in your case `public function setId($id)`. Zend_Form constructor checks if setter method exists for the property, if it exists then it is called, otherwise it sets the attribute of the form, see `setAttrib($key, $value)`.

The end result will be something like this

```
class Application_Form_YourForm extends Zend_Form {

    /**
     * Id
     * @var <type> 
     */
    protected $_id = null;

    /**
     * Setter for ID
     * @param <type> $id 
     */
    public function setId($id){
        $this->_id = $id;
    }

    // Rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: Simple solution to a seemingly complicated issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to access the `id` property inside the form with

```
$this->_attribs['id']
```